# Progress returning a 905 (11773) error from web service call

Tags: web-services, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm getting a 905 (11773) error when trying to send a web service call. I think it has something to do with the web service taking to long and some kind of internal progress timeout is being hit (I'm not setting any timeout). I'm thinking this because I can send small requests to this same web service and it works fine but large requests return with the above error. Any Ideas? Is there such a time out?

```
Error receiving Web Service Response:  (11773)

An error ocurred in the process of receiving a SOAP response message.  
The error details are appended.
```

but there are no details appended...

EDIT:
And before anyone asks I'm not using a `wait-for` and all the things that brings to the table.

Progress version: 11.3

It's a very simple connection and call. Just connect to the server, connect to the port, and make the call. There isn't any special code. I've striped it way down for testing. So I don't thing it's a coding issue, I think it's a progress config issue.

Not sure how it will help but here's my edited for stackoverflow code (note this is before trying the asynchronous stuff because it has the same result):

```
define variable hWebService as handle    no-undo.         /* Handle to Web Service */
define variable hPricePort  as handle    no-undo.         /* Handle to Web Service Price Port */
define variable cConnection as character no-undo.         /* Web Service host / connection string */ 
define variable lcPrices as longchar no-undo.
define variable lcOutput as longchar no-undo.

create server hWebService.
hWebService:connect(cConnection) no-error.
if error-status:error or not hWebService:connected() then do:
  delete object hWebService.
  message errMsg("Error WebService:connect(" + cConnection + ")").
  return.
end.

run PriceWebServiceSoap set hPricePort on hWebService no-error.
if error-status:error then do:
  delete object hWebService.
  message errMsg("Error setting adding pricing port: ").
  return
end.  /* if error-status:error */

run createPricesXml(input-output lcPrices).

run ImportRetailPrices in hPricePort (input lcPrices, output lcOutput) no-error.
if error-status:error then
  message errMsg("Error making price call:"). /* FROM THIS CHECK I'M GETTING: Unexpected response status code: 905 (11773) */ 

if valid-handle(hPricePort) then
delete procedure hPricePort no-error.

/* Close "connection" to the Web Service */
if valid-handle(hWebService) then do:
  if hWebService:connected() then
    hWebService:disconnect() no-error.
  delete object hWebService no-error.
end.
```

Comment: What version of OE? (And perhaps post some code - that might help...)

Comment: I'm unsure how (if) you can increase the timout. Test -clientConnectTimeout <n> in the CONNECT statement. Otherwise make the call asynchronous (you should most likely do that anyway) and you have greater control over timeouts. Check out the [docs](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvwsv/dvwsv.pdf)

Comment: -clientConnectTimeout is something else. that's the time it will wait to connect. I'm connecting just fine. It's the call that is erroring. I will look into asynchronous calls. thanks!

Comment: asynchronous isn't an option either because it would require the web service I'm connection to to change.

Comment: No its only a change on your side. Can post an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If it indeed is a timeout a good way to handle it is to use an asynchronous connection. That way you very easy change how long you wait for a response.

I have extensive experience of running webservices from OpenEdge and I don't think I've ever (or at least very rarely) seen a timeout. That might have to do with the stability of the webservice you are calling though. If it indeed is a timeout it will always happen after exactly the same time. How long that time is I don't know. The online help (in 11.6 states that for pure sockets the timeout is non existant and the session will wait forever).

Asynchronous request is always a good idea for external services since you can handle strange behavior better.

Below you see a simple example of how to run async. Connection, disconnection and cleanup left out.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE phPort      AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hHandle     AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE glcRequest  AS LONGCHAR   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE glcResponse AS LONGCHAR   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE glReply     AS LOGICAL     NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE iTimeOut AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO INITIAL 60.


/* This procedure will run when a response is recieved */
PROCEDURE WebServiceReply:
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcRequest  AS LONGCHAR   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER pcResponse AS LONGCHAR   NO-UNDO.
    glReply = TRUE.

    /* This is where the response should be handled */
END.

/* 
Connect left out 
*/
RUN WebService IN phPort ASYNCHRONOUS SET hHandle
    EVENT-PROCEDURE "WebServiceReply" 
    ( INPUT  glcRequest
    , OUTPUT glcResponse ) .

WAIT-FOR PROCEDURE-COMPLETE OF hHandle PAUSE iTimeOut.

IF glReply = FALSE THEN  DO:

    MESSAGE "No response recieved" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.

    hHandle:SERVER:CANCEL-REQUESTS().
    PROCESS EVENTS.

END.
```

**General Troubleshooting of Web Services**

When running into problems with Web Service calls I find it easy to use a proxy that log all requests and responses. There are several available but why not try one that's owned by Progress: [Telerik Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

You will need to download and install Telerik First.

To your Progress startup you add two parameters:

```
-proxyhost localhost -proxyport 8888
```

8888 is Telerik default proxy port. Change it if you like, but change it in Fiddler then aswell. Run the proxy on your local machine - that will be the easiest.

Now if you start your Progress session again all web services will be called via the proxy and Fiddler will record all data going in and out. Perhaps you can spot something strange?

**If all else fails**

If you're on an active license you can always log a request case with Progress.

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't know you could use a asynchronous connection like this. BUT unfortunately I get the same error: Unexpected response status code: 905 (11773)
Any other ideas?

Comment: Post your code, even though you think it's not the problem!

Comment: Posted (more characters)

Comment: Looks good but hard to say without xml, wsdl etc. Perhaps you need to check the SOAP-headers etc for error info. I find using a proxy very good when troubleshooting web services. I'll add some info to my response.

Comment: I have a solution but I don't know why it works, hopefully I can properly explain it. We have a long running batch progress session. Which all the jobs from a server are run on. If I stop and start this session I no longer get this error. This session can run for up to a week. I don't know how long it will take to come back.

Comment: Might be a memory leak. Log a support case if you have support!